# Prevent ApplicationNotResponding during debugging

Tags: android, debugging, android-anr-dialog

I am quite new to Android and have a debugging issue. I know what an ANR is for, and do not see them when I run my app normally. However, when I try to debug my BoradcastReceiver, I am too slow and get the ANR message.

Is there a way to switch off ANR during debug sessions? I could use log statement to see what's happening, but this is annoying....

edit: actually, I don't want to supress the ANRs in the LogCat, I want to tell android not to throw ANRs during debugging. I mean to allow Broadcast receivers to take longer than 5 seconds to run. But I guess it will not be possible and instead I should delegate to a service, which is allowed to run longer, which I also can debug easier.

Thanks in advance!

greets

Comment: I've been wondering the exact same thing, and still haven't found a solution to this problem.

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this, did you manager to solve it?

Comment: 2015 and still no solution... or did I miss something?

Comment: 2017 and still no solution... or did I miss something? :D

Comment: 2019 and still no solution... or did I miss something?

Comment: 2021 and still no solution... or did I miss something?

Comment: 2022 and still no solution... or did I miss something?

Comment: I think this answer is the solution to avoid the ANR dialogs, at least on recent API levels: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69585891/1152134

Answer (score 14):

Go to Settings -> Developer options and check Show all ANRs.

This will show an App Not Responding dialog for apps running in the background. You can click the Wait button in the dialog to prevent the system from killing your process. Note that the dialog is opened automatically for apps running in the foreground. For background apps, you have to enable this option.

Comment: Do you know, since whan this option is available?

Answer (score 2):

You may find [this resource](http://android-dev-life.blogspot.com/2015/02/do-you-adb-shell-am-set-debug-app.html) useful for your problem. Key points:

- Use -w to make process wait until debugger is attached. This one actually helps to stop on breakpoints on onCreate()'s. Debug flag is cleared after you attach debugger. Next time app starts in a regular way.
- Use --persistent to wait for debugger every time process starts.
- Use `adb shell am clear-debug-app your.app.package` to undo --persistent

Comment: I really like how an 8 year old question still delivers value. Thanks for adding!

Answer (score 1):

No. This message is handled through the Android OS, not your application, and there is no way to hide it on the Emulator. If you don't want to see it and your `BroadcastReceiver` receives the call correctly, just doesn't run successful code, you can use a try-catch block, and instead of your application crashing, the catch will be handled, wherein you can make a Toast message or whatever you wish.

Comment: seems I did not state clearly, what my intentions are. I will edit my original post. but thanks!