# Android kills app when debugging push notifications

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using Android Studio to debug push notifications on my app (attached to real device). I've put a breakpoint to push handler, and I start debugging. However, 30-40 seconds in, my app is always killed by the ActivityManager due to ANR. The app is obviously not responding, because I'm debugging it. On the middle of my debugging session, everything is gone, and I need to start over (and I have 30 seconds or so to debug the next time, too). It's extremely inconvenient.

I've extended `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` and handling the pushes in `onReceive` method.

Here is the Logcat output:

```
07-01 12:00:54.586    2280-2321/system_process E/ActivityManager﹕ ANR in com.ulouder.ulouder
    PID: 1270
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.ulouder.ulouder cmp=com.ulouder.ulouder/com.ulouder.PushHandler (has extras) }
    Load: 0.6 / 0.66 / 0.61
    CPU usage from 45803ms to 0ms ago:
    15% 2402/com.android.systemui: 12% user + 2.9% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    14% 1894/surfaceflinger: 5.3% user + 9.2% kernel
    0.8% 2280/system_server: 0.3% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 97 minor
    0.6% 1909/adbd: 0.1% user + 0.5% kernel
    0.4% 28003/kworker/u:1: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
    0.3% 309/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
    0.4% 1628/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
    0.3% 1066/kworker/u:2: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
    0.1% 748/s3c-fb-vsync: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0.1% 1270/com.ulouder.ulouder: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    0.1% 1502/kworker/u:3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0.1% 2528/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0% 968/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
    0% 2660/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 29958/com.facebook.katana: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 58 minor
    0% 1895/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 85 minor
    0% 2545/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 7/watchdog/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 433/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 1111/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 1342/com.google.android.apps.magazines: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 19 minor
    0% 2527/dhd_watchdog_th: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 2563/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    0% 2872/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel
    9.3% TOTAL: 5.3% user + 4% kernel + 0% iowait + 0% softirq
    CPU usage from 3199ms to 3716ms later:
    80% 1733/app_process: 65% user + 15% kernel / faults: 8231 minor
    75% 1733/app_process: 61% user + 13% kernel
    +0% 1734/ReferenceQueueD: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 1735/FinalizerDaemon: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 1736/FinalizerWatchd: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 1737/GC: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 1738/Signal Catcher: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 1739/JDWP: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 1740/Compiler: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 1741/Binder_1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 1742/Binder_2: 0% user + 0% kernel
    29% 2280/system_server: 18% user + 11% kernel / faults: 206 minor
    20% 2329/PackageManager: 18% user + 1.8% kernel
    7.4% 2321/ActivityManager: 0% user + 7.4% kernel
    1.8% 2624/Binder_9: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    5.5% 831/com.android.defcontainer: 1.1% user + 4.4% kernel / faults: 223 minor
    3.3% 843/Binder_1: 0% user + 3.3% kernel
    +0% 1743/IntentService[D: 0% user + 0% kernel
    1.1% 1284/logcat: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
    1.1% 1628/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
    1.8% 1909/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    1.8% 1909/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    37% TOTAL: 28% user + 8.4% kernel
```

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Logcat and some code please ?

Comment: IMHO: log everything and debug from that; if you have any complicated logic inside BroadcastReceiver then move it e.g. to Service, you will be able to debug there without ANR

Comment: @jmuet I could, but it's a bit overkill and inconvenient. I'm looking for a way (like a simple switch/flag in debugger or within Android) that would enable me to debug this way (without killing), if possible.

Comment: maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124711/prevent-applicationnotresponding-during-debugging