# Disable ANR messages while debugging

Tags: android, android-debug, android-anr-dialog

While debugging an application and stopped at a breakpoint, Android repeatedly displays "<Application> isn't responding. Do you want to close it?" dialogs with a "wait" and "ok" option. Is there any way to disable those while an application is being debugged?

Comment: This is still an issue, other questions are years older and their answers actually explain how to get this level of behaviour that we now want to get past. I need time to actually analyze the debug info. The app should not be killed while at a breakpoint.

Comment: is this still a thing nowadays?

Comment: I noticed it just a day or two ago.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Android 11

Comment: It still happens for example while in lldb session, my app is in "Select debugging app".  The only solution is to not stay too long in debug session :-( I use newest AndroidStudio, device is pixel 4a with android 13.

Answer (score 22):

In the **Developer Options** scroll down to the **Debugging** section and choose your app in "**Select debugging app**". This way it will not trigger any ANR when paused in a breakpoint.
The setting value will be remembered even if you remove/reinstall your app.

Note that this option may not be available depending on your API level.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is the perfect solution for ANR during debugging

Comment: This is the ONLY solution, and it's really far from perfect. It's actually pretty annoying as soon as you work on more than 1 application. I still don't understand why ANR security is enabled in debug apps in the first place…

Answer (score 0):

When the app stops at the breakpoint

ANR is thought to have occurred by the system

But really you're just waiting for the break point

The system doesn't know that

dialog show by System

No need to pop anr when debug is not considered

I think unless you modify the system source code， Take that into account

I hope I can help you : )

Answer (score -1):

An ANR will be triggered for your app when one of the following conditions occur:

- While your activity is in the foreground, your app has not responded to an input event or BroadcastReceiver (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
- While you do not have an activity in the foreground, your BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within a considerable amount of time.

I'm not sure what is your case here but when debugging just **don't interact with the app** (such as click button, tab on screen) and then the app will wait for the debugger.

Answer (score -3):

If your applications shows that message when is not staying on breakpoint there is definitely too much computation on the main thread and you should get rid of complex calculations on main thread and move them to background threads

Comment: The question is specifically about Android showing the message while stopped at a breakpoint.